# Clang-format: space before unary operator

Tags: c++, clang-format, unary-operator

I would like to configure clang-format to put a space before unary operators (to increase readability):

- Instead of:

  i++;
- I would like:

  i ++;

Is it possible? (I can't find anything about this in the documentation.)
If not, could one submit a feature request for clang-format?

Comment: Do you actually find `i ++;` *more* readable? Besides, you should prefer pre-increment.

Comment: Please: This is not a debate about coding conventions preferences (this is highly subjective). This is not a debate about post vs pre increment (modern compilers make this question useless). Since Clang-format allows many spacing configurations, such as SpaceAfterLogicalNot: true, and PointerAlignment: Middle, I think it would make sense to control the spacing for unary operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, **No.** There is no option for formatting unary operator `(i++ -> i ++)` in clang-format neither it's written in its [official and most trusted](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) documentation and other sites.

Secondly, the basic convention has always been `i++` rather than `i ++` (for most programmers) in programming languages. So, it doesn't seems if anyone would have suggested to update it. It already looks cool.